# Error al ejecutar stored procedure (PLS 00103)

Tags: php, oracle, plsql

Mi problema es el siguiente...
Tengo un procedure creado que quiero ejecutar desde php y al hacerlo me tira el siguiente error:

> [Error] Execution (12: 51): ORA-06550: line 1, column 51:
> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:
> begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod
> null pragma raise return select update while with
>  
>  << close current delete fetch lock insert
> open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge
> pipe

El código es el siguiente:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CTACTE.cte_cpa_vuelco_datos(p_archivo in varchar2,p_usuario in varchar2) IS
Xestado NUMBER :=0;
/*******************/
/*P_USUARIO VARCHAR2(60):=USER;*/
cursor c1 is
SELECT 
 TO_DATE(NVL(FECHA_PAGO,SYSDATE),'DD/MM/YYYY')   FECHA
,lpad(REPLACE(CODIGO_CURSO,'.'),5,'0')          CODIGO
,ROUND(IMPORTE_CURSO)                           IMPORTE
,ROUND(IMPORTE_PAGO)                            IMPORTE_PAGO 
,UPPER(MEDIO_COBRO)                             MPACODIGO
,PER_LIMPIA_CARACTERES(UPPER(NOMBRE_ALUMNO))    NOMBRE
,PER_LIMPIA_CARACTERES(UPPER(APELLIDO_ALUMNO))  APELLIDO
,PER_LIMPIA_CARACTERES(UPPER(EMAIL_ALUMNO))     MAIL 
,PER_LIMPIA_CARACTERES(UPPER(CALLE))            CALLE
,TO_CHAR(REPLACE(CALLE_NRO,'.'))                NUMERO
,TO_CHAR(REPLACE(PISO,'.'))                     PISO
,TO_CHAR(REPLACE(DEPARTAMENTO,'.'))             DEPTO
,TO_CHAR(REPLACE(CODIGO_POSTAL,'.'))            CODPOST
,TO_CHAR(REPLACE(TIPO_DOCUMENTO,'.'))           TIPODOC
,TO_CHAR(REPLACE(NRO_DOCUMENTO,'.'))            NUMERO_DOC
,to_char(MONEDA,'000') MONEDA
,CODIGO_PAIS PAIS
,TRIM(REPLACE(NRO_COBRO,'.')) COBRO
,NOMBRE_ARCHIVO
FROM IMPORTA_NOV_LEARNING
WHERE NOMBRE_ARCHIVO =p_archivo;
r1 c1%rowtype;
r01 c1%rowtype;

CURSOR C_CTRL (P_NOMBRE IN VARCHAR)IS
SELECT 0 existe FROM CTE_PROGRAMAS_ACADEMICOS 
WHERE  NOMBRE_ARCHIVO =  P_NOMBRE;
R_CTRL C_CTRL%ROWTYPE;

secu  number;
/******************************************************************************
   NAME:       cte_cpa_vuelco_datos
   PURPOSE:    

   REVISIONS:
   Ver        Date        Author           Description
   ---------  ----------  ---------------  ------------------------------------
   1.0        29/11/2018          1. Created this procedure.

   NOTES:

   Automatically available Auto Replace Keywords:
      Object Name:     cte_cpa_vuelco_datos
      Sysdate:         29/11/2018
      Date and Time:   29/11/2018, 12:27:43 p.m., and 29/11/2018 12:27:43 p.m.
      Username:         (set in TOAD Options, Procedure Editor)
      Table Name:       (set in the "New PL/SQL Object" dialog)

******************************************************************************/
BEGIN
open c1;
fetch c1 into r01;
CLOSE C1;


open c_ctrl(r01.NOMBRE_ARCHIVO);
fetch c_ctrl into r_ctrl;
close c_ctrl;

if  r_ctrl.existe = 0 then
    raise_application_error(-20000,'El archivo '||r01.NOMBRE_ARCHIVO||'.CSV  ya ha sido importado ');
    return;
end if;

open c1;
    loop
    fetch c1 into r1;
    exit when c1%notfound;
        begin
        SELECT CTE_CPA_NUMERO.NEXTVAL INTO SECU FROM DUAL; 
            --
            INSERT INTO cte_programas_academicos(
                CPA_NUMERO             ,
                CPA_FECHA_IMPORTACION  ,
                CPA_FECHA              ,
                CPA_CURSO              ,
                CPA_IMPORTE            ,
                CPA_IMPORTE_PAGADO     ,
                CPA_COBRO              ,
                NOMBRE                 ,
                APELLIDO               ,
                MAIL                   ,
                CALLE                  ,
                NUMERO                 ,
                PISO                   ,
                DEPTO                  ,
                CODPOST                ,
                TIPODOC                ,
                NUMERO_DOC             ,
                MON_CODIGO             ,
                PAIS_CODIGO            ,
                COD_COBRO              ,
                ESTADO                 ,
                NOMBRE_ARCHIVO         ,
                USR_NOMBRE_ALTA  
                )
                VALUES(  
                 SECU
                ,SYSDATE
                ,R1.FECHA
                ,R1.CODIGO
                ,R1.IMPORTE
                ,R1.IMPORTE_PAGO
                ,R1.MPACODIGO
                ,R1.NOMBRE
                ,R1.APELLIDO
                ,R1.MAIL
                ,R1.CALLE
                ,R1.NUMERO
                ,R1.PISO
                ,R1.DEPTO
                ,R1.CODPOST
                ,R1.TIPODOC
                ,R1.NUMERO_DOC
                ,'080'
                ,R1.PAIS
                ,R1.COBRO
                ,Xestado 
                ,R1.NOMBRE_ARCHIVO
                ,P_USUARIO
                );
        end;
    end loop;
    close c1;
      EXCEPTION
     WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
       NULL;
     --WHEN OTHERS THEN
     --raise;
       -- Consider logging the error and then re-raise
      -- raise_application_error(-20001,sqlerrm);
END cte_cpa_vuelco_datos;
/
```

No logro darme cuenta de cuál es la línea donde está el "end-of-file" del que me habla... ¿alguna idea?
Desde ya muchas gracias!

**EDIT:** El código de la llamada es el siguiente:

```
if ($_GET['Opcion']=='vuelco') {

    $qry0 = "select max(nombre_archivo) from IMPORTA_NOV_LEARNING";
    $r0 = xQuery($qry0);
    $row1 = oci_fetch_row($r0);
    $_SESSION['archivo']=$row1[0];

$prc1 = 0;
$prc2 = 0;

    $query = "begin cte_cpa_vuelco_datos('".$_SESSION['archivo']."','".$_SESSION['UserName']."'); end;";
    $stmt = oci_parse($conn,$query);
    $r=oci_execute($stmt,OCI_COMMIT_ON_SUCCESS);
    $_SESSION['insert']=1;
    $prc1 = 1;
    if (!$r) {
        $prc1 = 0;
        $_SESSION['insert']=0;  
        $e = oci_error($stmt);                      //
        $msj=htmlentities($e['message']);           //  
        $conservar = '0-9a-z.';                     // 
        $regex = sprintf('~[^%s]++~i', $conservar); // 
        $string = preg_replace($regex, ' ', $msj);  // 
        $string =str_replace('quot',' ',$string);   //
        echo $query."</br>";
        echo '<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="javascript">';
        echo 'var msj ="'.$string.'";';
        echo 'alert("Atencion1!\n"+msj);';
        echo '</SCRIPT>'; 
    }    
    oci_free_statement($stmt);

}
```

Esto es así:
Tengo un form para subida de archivos (reportes). Estos archivos son procesados y guardados en una DB.
Una vez hecho esto, se vuelcan dichos archivos en una tabla HTML para poder verse en web. Para esto, llamo a este procedure y le paso el nombre del archivo.
Pero por alguna razón, hay un error al ejecutar el procedure.

Comment: Si el error ocurre al hacer la llamada, muestra el código de la llamada. ¿El procedimiento ya está compilado? por que el error que mencionas es uno de compilación.

Comment: Ahí edité el post.

Comment: No-respuesta: No hay que olvidar dejar el WHEN OTHERS siempre habilitado para que controles cualquier excepción. Así mismo, ese abrir y cerrar el cursor c1 es costoso en tiempo. puedes hacer el primer fetch, validar luego hacer el loop y al final cerrarlo.

Comment: El error básicamente te está diciendo que tienes un problema de sintaxis y debes arreglarlo (es un "falta un paréntesis" versión PLSQL). Prueba simplificando el procedimiento y luego ve añadiendo partes del mismo, para ver cuál tiene líos. Haz que el bloque implícito haga sólo el select into secu y mira a ver si así compila sin errores. Luego añade el insert y reemplaza el procedure, a ver si complia sin errores, etc.

Comment: Revisa el valor de `$query`.

Comment: Por cierto, deberías hacer *binding*, ej. con `oci_bind_by_name()`